# how can I parametrize the spring constructor-arg injection based on the property file or environmental variable?

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml

I have the following constructor in my `spring` application:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:metadata/idp-test.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Now, I have 2 different xml config files, one for test env and one for prod env. Is there a way in the config above to have some kind of `switch` (or `if-else` perhaps?), based on which there would be either the `idp-test.xml` or a different one `idp-prod.xml` injected? I assume it would be based on the property file or e.g. environmental variable, that would store the info which environment is it (test or prod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the profile feature which allow you to enable a bean only if certain profile is activated ?

If yes, you can first configuring a profile for the bean :

```xml
<beans profile="prod">
  <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
  </bean>
</bean>

<beans profile="test">
  <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
  </bean>
</bean>
```

And [activating a particular profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-enable) by configuring the JVM system property `spring.profiles.active` in the command that start JVM :

```
 -Dspring.profiles.active="prod"
```

Or activate from the environment variable:

```sh
export spring_profiles_active=prod
```

In this case , only the bean with `prod` profile and without specifying any profile will be enabled.

Comment: Thank you, one question though - when I added the profile to the bean, I'm getting the message `Attribute profile is not allowed here`, so it seems like the intellij does not accept it there... Is there a way of fixing that?

Comment: sorry. a typo for me . please see my update . it should be added in the `<beans>`